# php constructor class pass object

Tags: php, class

Ok I changed this question completely up. Trying not to give all info. But enough to see if you can spot the problem.

DB class.

```
class dbHandler {
    private $dbConn;
    private $config;
    private $cwd;

    public function  __construct()
    {
        $this->cwd = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/ccrm';
        $this->config = parse_ini_file($this->cwd.'/../../glossary.config.ini'); // -- for local

        require_once('_mssql.php');
        require_once('_mysql.php');
    }
```

glossary class

```
class glossaryHandler {

    private $dbHandler;
    private $cwd;
    // this is the constructor this constructor runs on creation of object
    public function  __construct($db)
    {
        $this->dbHandler = $db;
    }
```

file that is included (header.php)

```
require_once($cwd.'/resources/php/_dbHandler.php');
    $db = new dbHandler;
require_once($cwd.'/resources/php/_glossaryHandler.php');
$glossaryHandler = new glossaryHandler($db);
```

Error Given

Notice: Undefined variable: db

Comment: ok first. off. I noticed my my mistake here. I got this working. but I tried doing the same thing on the other and it doesn't work. For whatever reason.

here the issue was changing $this->$t to $this->t

Comment: `$this->t` means "the class variable named `t`". `$this->$t` means "the class variable named by the contents of the local variable `$t`"

Comment: Yeah.mine is much more complicated. Than this. But I can't expose code. :( I hate NDAs. It's all about passing a DB object to another class. But when I go to assign the object to a local var. It says undefined var.

Comment: Well, you've got the var defined as private in this example, so you won't be able to access it outside the class, if that's what you're trying to do.

Comment: @AlexHowansky - I updated question. Maybe you can help. I was able to ask my boss and he said I can post this much code.

Comment: This code is fine, your error is elsewhere.

Comment: This is the code. It doesn't like me passing that db object. It says it's undefined?

Comment: OMG @AlexHowansky -- I HATE YOU!!! hahhaa. Thanks. . I noticed. my issue. I was trying to create the glossary handler again on the page that was requiring the header. You're awesome man! Thank you.

Comment: Heh sometimes the stupidest of mistakes take two sets of eyes to find...